# SQL query for fetching a single column with multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle10g

Consider the below table:

Table1

```
id | status
------------
1  | A
2  | B
3  | C
1  | B
4  | B
5  | C
4  | A
```

Desired output is 1 and 4 as they are having status as both 'A' and 'B'.

Can we write an query for this? I tried to query it using conditions like 'AND', 'UNION' and 'OR', but it did not return me the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the ids with more than 1 statuses:

```
select id
from tablename
group by id
having count(distinct status) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select id
from t
where status in ('A', 'B')
group by id
having count(*) = 2;
```

If the table allows duplicates, then use `count(distinct status) = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, you can do without using `having()` as well

```
select
    id
from
(
    select
        id,
        count(distinct status) as cnt
    from yourTable
    group by
        id
) val
where cnt > 1
```

Comment: Why do you need the outer query>

Comment: Just wanted to do without using `having` clause and if need display id between specific count range. Let me know if there is any drawback. Thanks